# How to use npm-check

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have been playing around with node.js and learning by playing with the Spotify API.

Spotify provided example source code which I have been building off but now I want to make my own thing.

There are many modules in node_module for use for their different examples and I obviously don't want any packages I am not using being hosted on my Git so I looking into my options and came across npm-check (https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check)

I did

```
npm install npm-check
```

and it was successful

I then try to run the npm-check command in the folder my app.js is contained in like so

```
npm-check
```

I then get an error saying it is not a recognized command.

what am I missing?

Comment: it isn't installed globally (and therefore isn't on your path.) `node_modules/.bin/npm-check`

Comment: That is it. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`npm install` only installs the npm module into the directory you are currently in., After running that command, you should see a `node_modules` directory with the `npm-check` module and all of it's dependencies.

To run npm check here, you would need to run `/path/to/.bin/npm-check`

If you would like to be able to run `npm-check` from any directory by simply running `npm-check`, you must first install it globally:

`npm install -g npm-check`